# HTML Form with PHP Captcha Plugin, I'm running into some issues

Tags: php, javascript, captcha, forms

I have looked for similar questions and I did not find my particular case.

I am using the PHP Captcha plugin within a form that I have. I handle the incorrect and correct captcha entries very similar. If the user's phrase is correct I throw a javascript "success" alert, send the form email, and then send them back to the last page. If incorrect I throw a javascript "your incorrect" alert and send them back to the last page.

My problem- if they are incorrect I need to refresh Captcha because with an incorrect Captcha entry you will always need to refresh the image for another attempt. Also if they are correct I want the field cleared but only cleared when correct, if incorrect I want to keep the forms data. How can I do this?

Here is my PHP captcha code so you can see my attempt. Let me know if you want the html... (also I checked all entries with JS before POST)

```
<?php
/*set email*/
  $myemail  = "email@email.com";

  /* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
$name = $_POST['name'];
$companyName  = $_POST['companyName'];
$phone    = $_POST['phone'];
$email  = $_POST['email'];
$TimeForContact   = $_POST['TimeForContact'];
$aval = $_POST['aval'];
$messageFromFrom = $_POST['message'];
$firstTime = $_POST['firstTime'];
$subject = "Some Subject";

  require_once('recaptcha-php-1.11/recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "*someprivatekey*"; //I took this out for the question
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly

echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert ("You have inserted the wrong phrase in the Captcha box. Please try again! Thank you."); window.history.back();</script>';
          exit();

  } else {

  $message = "some message

End of message
";

/* Send the message using mail() function */
mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

          echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert ("Success! You have emailed your submission. Please await our response. Thank you."); window.history.back()</script>';


exit();
  }

?>
```

I originally tried reloading the page through JS, like:

```
window.reload(history.back());
```

or

```
window.location.reload(history.go(-1));
```

no success with either + multiple combinations similar to that.

So to reiterate the question:
How can I refresh form/captcha when desired

OR

What is your practiced behavior for submitting a captcha form?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing something like this. Essentially checking for errors and pushing errors into an error array that you can later loop over and display to the user. Upon submit, you check the recaptcha and if its invalid, it will automatically clear the field. Do not use alerts or exit() or anything of that sort, a simple $errors array should suffice.

```
//untested code
<?php

//check to make sure they submitted the form
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $errors = array();

    $myemail  = "email@email.com";
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $companyName  = $_POST['companyName'];
    /* ... */

    //recaptcha check
    require_once('recaptcha-php-1.11/recaptchalib.php');
    $privatekey = "*someprivatekey*";
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer (
        $privatekey,$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
        $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
        $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]
    );

    //validate all data here
    if (!$resp->is_valid) {
        array_push($errors, "recaptcha invalid please try again");
    }else if( /* name is invalid */) {
        array_push($errors, "name invalid");
    }else if (){
        /* keep validing ...... with else if*/
    }

    /*....*/

    else{
        //everything validated so were good
        mail($myemail, $subject, $message);  
    }

}

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="process.php">
        <!-- Your form here, "process.php" is this page itself -->
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```